# Rem in Susy Grid setup

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass, grid-layout

I have built a site using Susy and the grid was specified in em's but due to hitting an issue, I need to change the grid settings to use rems.

My base font size set on html is 16px and this is the setup for Susy grid settings:

```
$total-columns    : 16
$column-width     : remCalc(51.25px)
$gutter-width     : remCalc(10px)
$grid-padding     : remCalc(10px)
$container-style  : magic
```

The remCalc function is:

```
@function remCalc($pxWidth)
  @return parseInt($pxWidth) / parseInt($base-font-size) * 1rem
```

But when compiling this I get:

> (Line 146 of _functions.scss: 0.01031em/rem is not a unitless number
>   for `percentage')

Using rem or the main grid settings would solve my issues. I also updated Susy to 1.0.8 from 1.0.3 but that has had no effect either.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's happening at line 146? I would guess you used ems in something like at-breakpoint.

Comment: Line 146 is not one of my files. I guess thats one of Susy's files but I guess the breakpoint issue sounds reasonable and will try it out tommorrow! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by updating the unit on another Sass variable elsewhere in the project. Jesse's answer, whilst not solving this issue, is also extremely helpful and useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your configuration:

```
// Vertical Rhythm Config
$rhythm-unit          : rem;
$base-rhythm-unit     : <number>rem;
$relative-font-sizing : true;

// Susy Config
$column-width : <number>rem;
$gutter-width : <number>rem;
$grid-padding : <number>rem;
```

Where `<number>` is your preferred sizing. `$rhythm-unit` is the operative variable though, you might need to go to an alpha version of Compass to get it though, and maybe even Susy 1.0.9 as well.

You can use the rem mixin (included with Susy) for creating fallbacks to px.
i.e:

```
@include rem(height, image-height('image.png'));
```

As long as you leave `$base-font-size` and `$base-line-height` the same, I think you'll be ok. If you do get weird sizing just go through and tweak your values. `susy-grid-background` would probably help you get through any weirdness as well.

Edit: I also think you want to be using whole numbers for your base grid sizes. Your conversion is probably messing with how Susy does the math to create the grid.

Comment: Much appreciate your answer. As I asked this a month ago, I did manage to solve this on my own. Had a rogue unit elsewhere in my styles. Since that site I have been using rems more and more and am pretty much using what you explained and it's working really well. Thanks! I'll +1 this answer but as this was not the exact solution to the issue, i'll add another answer explaining it to help others if they need it. Thanks again!